# Eigenvalue calculation for a Java matrix library

Tags: java, performance, matrix, mathematics

After an interview didn't go smoothly, I decided to write my own library so that I would be better prepared if I'm ever asked about matrix multiplication again.

I know that doing it in Java is going to sacrifice some performance (at least I think I do). Also, I know that there are libraries already made for this purpose. The point is to learn enough to be able to off the cuff handle virtually any matrix algorithm I may need to, and to learn where to find the answers to the ones I don't. And I'm doing it in Java to flesh out my understanding of the language.

I've got most of what I set out to do in the library accomplished, except the final part: eigenvalues.

I've implemented a fairly basic [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) method, and it seems to work (read: compare a bunch of random matrices in my library with the output of trusted calculators).

The problem is that it's orders of magnitude too slow. For a 50x50 matrix it takes almost a minute to get the eigenvalues.

Right now that's because I've set the iterations to 500 to handle a pathological case I came across when testing it. I'd like to reduce the number of iterations in order to something like 10, which for almost every matrix is sufficient to make it converge.

I looked around the web, and found a paper talking about advanced QR methods. Basically, from what I understand of the paper, if you first convert the matrix to upper Hessenberg form, it should converge orders of magnitude faster. Further, if you implement shifting, it should converge quadratically.

I read and implemented, I think, those two algorithms. They do make the convergence faster; the problem is that now it fails the previous problem test case, spitting out the wrong eigenvalues silently.

I don't understand why. The paper says, paraphrasing through my limited math understanding, that if a matrix A is put through a Hessenberg transformation H(A), it should still have the same eigenvalues. And the same with shifting.

My problem is either I've implemented the algorithm incorrectly, or I'm misunderstanding the math behind it.

[The paper I was talking about for reference](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter3.pdf)

[The repository link](https://github.com/rwthompsonii/matrix-java/tree/d6b3843cd6eff89df8de55c6c32570d6d241a871)

The relevant function:

```
public static Complex[] eigenvalues(SquareMatrix A) {
    Complex[] e = new Complex[A.getRows()];

    QRDecomposition qr = new QRDecomposition();

    qr.iterations = 0;
    int total_iter = 0;
    int num_eigen_found = 0;
    SquareMatrix QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(A);

    //in general, QR decomposition will converge faster from an upper
    //Hessenberg matrix.  so, first things first, we bring QRIterator to that form
    //QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(qr.hessenberg(QRIterator));

    int max = MAX_ITERATIONS;
    //double lastElement;
    //SquareMatrix ScaledIdentity;
    do {

        System.out.println("Pre-decompose: QRIterator (Iteration#" + (qr.iterations + 1) + "):\n" + QRIterator);
        if (QRIterator.getRows() == 1) {
            //very last 1x1 element in matrix
            e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex(
                    QRIterator.getMatrix()[0][0]
            );
            break;
        } else {

            /*lastElement = QRIterator.getMatrix()[QRIterator.getRows() - 1][QRIterator.getColumns() - 1];
            ScaledIdentity = new SquareMatrix(Matrix.IdentityMatrix(QRIterator.getRows()).scale(lastElement));
            try {
                QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(QRIterator.subtract(ScaledIdentity));
            } catch (DimensionMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected execption during QRIterator -= I*alpha, bailing.");
                System.exit(-1);

            }*/
            qr.decompose(QRIterator);
        }
        try {
            QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(qr.R.mult(qr.Q)/*.add(ScaledIdentity)*/);

        } catch (DimensionMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("An unexpected exception occurred during QRIterator = R*Q, bailing.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        qr.iterations++;

        //testing indicates that MAX_ITERATIONS iterations should be more than sufficient to converge, if its going to at all
        if (qr.iterations == max || Math.abs(QRIterator.getMatrix()[QRIterator.getRows() - 1][QRIterator.getColumns() - 2]) < CONVERGENCE_CHECK) {
            System.out.println("QRIterator (at max iteration or converged) (Iteration#" + (qr.iterations + 1) + "):\n" + QRIterator);
            if (Math.abs(QRIterator.getMatrix()[QRIterator.getRows() - 1][QRIterator.getColumns() - 2]) < CONVERGENCE_CHECK) {
                //then the value at M[n][n] is an eigenvalue and it is real
                e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex(
                        QRIterator.getMatrix()[QRIterator.getRows() - 1][QRIterator.getColumns() - 1]
                );

                //System.out.println("e[" + (num_eigen_found - 1) + "]:\t" + e[num_eigen_found - 1] + "\nQRIterator before deflation:\n" + QRIterator);
                double[][] deflatedMatrix = deflate(QRIterator.getMatrix(), 1);
                QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(deflatedMatrix);

                //System.out.println("\nQRIterator after deflation:\n" + QRIterator);
                total_iter += qr.iterations;
                qr.iterations = 0;  //reset the iterations counter to find the next eigenvalue
            } else {
                //this is a 2x2 matrix with either real or complex roots.  need to find them.
                //characteristic equation of 2x2 array => E^2 - (w + z)E + (wz - xy) = 0 where E = eigenvalue (possibly pair, possibly singular, possibly real, possibly complex)
                // and the matrix {{w, x}, {y, z}} is the input array, the task is to calculate the root(s) of that equation
                //that is a quadratic equation => (root = (-b +- sqrt(b^2  - 4ac))/2a)
                //determinant b^2 - 4ac will determine behavior of roots => positive means 2 real roots, 0 means 1 repeated real root, negative means conjugate pair of imaginary roots

                //first, get the wxyz from the (possibly bigger) matrix
                int n = QRIterator.getRows();
                double w = QRIterator.getMatrix()[n - 2][n - 2];
                double x = QRIterator.getMatrix()[n - 2][n - 1];
                double y = QRIterator.getMatrix()[n - 1][n - 2];
                double z = QRIterator.getMatrix()[n - 1][n - 1];

                //a not used since it's = 1
                double b = -(w + z);
                double c = (w * z - x * y);

                //calculate determinant of quadratic equation
                double determ = b * b - 4 * c;

                if (determ >= 0) {
                    //one or two real roots 
                    double sqrt_determ_real = Math.sqrt(determ);
                    e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex((-b + sqrt_determ_real) / 2.0);
                    e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex((-b - sqrt_determ_real) / 2.0);
                    //in the zero determinant case that's simply going to add the same eigenvalue to the list twice.  I'm ok with that for now.
                } else if (determ < 0) {
                    //conjugate pair of complex roots
                    double sqrt_determ_imag = Math.sqrt(-determ);
                    e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex(-b / 2.0, sqrt_determ_imag / 2.0);
                    e[num_eigen_found++] = new Complex(-b / 2.0, -sqrt_determ_imag / 2.0);
                }

                if (QRIterator.getRows() > 2) {
                    total_iter += qr.iterations;
                    qr.iterations = 0;  //reset the iterations counter to find the next eigenvalue
                    double[][] deflatedMatrix = deflate(QRIterator.getMatrix(), 2);
                    QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(deflatedMatrix);
                } 
            }
        }
        //QRIterator = new SquareMatrix(qr.hessenberg(QRIterator));

    } while (qr.iterations < max);

    //used for debugging here
    /*System.out.println("Finished iterating.  Iterations:\t" + qr.iterations
     + "\nFinal value of qr.Q:\n" + qr.Q + "\nFinal value of qr.R:\n" + qr.R
     + "\nFinal value of QRIterator:\n" + QRIterator
     + "\nOriginal SquareMatrix A:\n" + A);
     */
    return e;
}
```

Comment: I understand, I'll try and get it working first, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't have any comments on the math, but I can offer some suggestions regarding the code...

## Names and comments

- `SquareMatrix QRIterator = ...` can be written as `SquareMatrix qrIterator`, following the usual Java `fields`-naming convention
- This is just a pet peeve of mine, but I associate the field `e` with an `Exception`, even though I understand it represents your `eigenvalues`. Probably just call it by that name?
- Same for the method name, perhaps rename it as `getEigenvalues()`?
- You have too much commented-out code, does that mean you have significant changes in your implementation/calculations? If so, why not consider branching in Git so that you can keep these to a minimum?

## Handling exceptions

This code block seems extremely *harsh*:

```
    try {
        ...
    } catch (DimensionMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("An unexpected exception occurred during QRIterator = R*Q, bailing.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

If you do turn this into a library in the future that can be used by other projects, you do not want to spring this surprise on them... If there are errors like this, should you simply re-throw the same error?

## `QRDecomposition`

I took a *real quick* look at this on the GitHub repository as well.

1. I don't think it is necessary for it to implement your `MatrixConstants` interface, since that interface appears to only contain fields, and not method declarations (actually, ditto this for the `Matrix` class too).
2. The `iterations` field seem to be unnecessary, as it is only used within this `eigenvalues()` method (so far). In this case, you just need a simple counter field within this method to do the same task.

Comment: "Eigenvalue" is considered a single word. I would not capitalize the "V" in the middle of it.

Comment: My math is rusty... :o (edited answer to reflect that).